# python, ImportError: No module named mayavi.modules.scalar_cut_plane

Tags: python, importerror, mayavi, ubuntu-13.10

I get the following error when i try to visualize something on a program that uses mayavi:

CONSOLE OUTPUT:

```
File "/home/meniwis/syscave/src/python/syscave/gui/flowsim3d.py", line 15, 
in <module> from mayavi.modules.scalar_cut_plane import ScalarCutPlane
ImportError: No module named mayavi.modules.scalar_cut_plane
```

Here the file "/home/meniwis/syscave/src/python/syscave/gui/flowsim3d.py :

```
line 01:import os
line 02:import sys
line 03:import sip
line 04:if sip.getapi('QString') >1:
line 05:    QString=unicode
line 06:
line 07:os.environ['ETS_TOOLKIT'] = 'qt4'
line 08:
line 09:import numpy as np
line 10:from numpy import linspace, pi, cos, sin
line 11:
line 12:try:
line 13:    from enthought.mayavi.modules.scalar_cut_plane import ScalarCutPlane
line 14:except ImportError:
line 15:    from mayavi.modules.scalar_cut_plane import ScalarCutPlane
```

I am using:

```
-Ubuntu 13.10
-Python 2.7
-epd-7.3-1-rh5-x86_64, which, as i know, comes with mayavi.
```

Any clue on what could be making the error?

Thank in advance.
Grettings.

Comment: How are you installing it? using pip?

Comment: Do you get an error if you open python and type `import mayavi` ?

Comment: @jonathanrocher, thanks for your answer. If i open a python's shell and type "import mayavi" i don't get any errors.

Comment: @void, thanks for your answer. When i get an "...No module named..." error, what i always do is "sudo apt-get install python-'module'". For example, in the begining i got "Importerror:No module name numpy(or elixir or hdf5 or etc,etc,etc)", so i did  "sudo apt-get install python-numpy(or elixir or alchemy or pyqt or etc,etc,etc)"

Comment: Look, always use pip to install python packages  and modules. Give this a try  `easy_install pip` then `pip install mayavi`